# Row separator on empty listview

Tags: wpf

How can I have a default row separator on `ListView` by default even when the it is empty?

By default it is empty. Do I have to do any style for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Listview empty text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019017/wpf-listview-empty-text)

Comment: No I want a empty listview with row seperator line.